# differences in behavior docker php - localhost

Tags: php, docker, localhost

I am currently working on a php project
which upon completion I must deploy it in a docker container.

To perform this task I am using the image:

8.1-apache-bullseye

I have the problem with the variable types, when comparing them:

```
$is_year    = 18; # Int
$get_year   = $_POST['year']; # String

if ($is_year == $get_year) {
    echo 'It does not work';
}

if ($is_year == (int)$get_year) {
    echo 'Works'; 
}
```

What occurs to me is that the php configuration of the docker container is different from that of my localhost.

Comment: Would bet, `$_POST['year']` contains white spaces, so the (int) casting works like a `intval()` operation. Is it good to have additional user input validation, you could also use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php